# How to create subtask of issue in jira kanban board

Tags: kanban, jira

I'm using Jira Business Project "Kanban" board.  I'd like to somehow group Issues on the board.

Use Cases:

1. One task is dependent (perhaps sequentially) on another. Example: Research existing solutions, Review existing solutions, mock up draft solution, final draft of solution)
2. Milestones or Goals  with tasks grouped for them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[From Help](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/manage-subtasks-in-team-managed-projects/)

[image]

You can create subtasks under any standard issues, like stories, bugs, or tasks. Note that you cannot create subtasks under epics or other subtasks.

When viewing an issue

On the board or backlog, select an issue.

Select Add a child issue

Enter a description for the subtask and select Create.